# The broker does not support the requested SASL mechanism

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, sasl, aws-msk, kafkajs

I have an MSK cluster in which i have used AWS IAM authentication .When i am telnet to the `broker:9098`, the broker gets connected .But when am passing the same `broker:9098` in a node app's kafka producer code, it shows `"The broker does not support the requested SASL mechanism"`.
my kafka producer code goes like:

```js
const { Kafka,logLevel } = require('kafkajs');

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'api_gateway_client',
    brokers: ["b-2.ashxxxxx.xx74.cx.kafka.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:9098"],
    ssl: true,
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'aws',
    authorizationIdentity: '8829xxx97', // UserId or RoleId
    accessKeyId: 'AKIA4xxxxxGD37NEJ',
    secretAccessKey: 'q7SI3xxxxxxiAou6TDXWdyR6h',
    //sessionToken: 'WHArYt8i5vfQUrIxxxxxeL9tgQMJp6QFNEXAMPLETOKEN' // Optional
  },
})
const producer = kafka.producer();
producer.connect();

export async function sendKafkaMessage(topic: string, message: string): Promise<any> {

    const result = await producer.send({
        topic,
        messages: [
            { value: message }
        ]
    });
    return result;
}

producer.on('producer.connect',async () => {
    console.log('Kafka producer connected ................');
    const admin = kafka.admin();
    const topic = "geolah"
    const result = await producer.send({
            topic,
            messages: [
                { value: "hii TOPIC" }
            ]
     });

});
```

Comment: Now, where are you running this code? If it's from your local machine, not in AWS, then you need to use port 9198

Comment: no i am running inside the VPC of my ec2

Comment: Are you using the correct bootstrap servers? Ideally you give more than one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-get-bootstrap-brokers.html

Comment: i am not able to list the bootstrap brokers using the AWS CLI with the right arn.but i i can list the cluster with aws cli

Comment: So the CLI isn't showing bootstrap brokers? Or your credentials are incorrect? Suggested before, I think AWS support would help more since your code here otherwise looks correct